# Antlr not recognizing number

Tags: parsing, numbers, antlr4, lexer, dynamic-languages

I have 3 types of numbers defined, number, decimal and percentage.

`Percentage : (Sign)? Digit+ (Dot Digit+)? '%' ;`
`Number     : Sign? Digit+;`
`Decimal        : Sign? Digit+ Dot Digit*;`

Percentage and decimal work fine but when I assign a number, unless I put a sign (+ or -) in front of the number, it doesn't recognize it as a number.
`number foo = +5  // does recognize`
`number foo = 5; // does not recognize`

It does recognize it in an evaluation expression.
`if (foo == 5 )  // does recognize`

Here is my language (I took out the functions and left only the language recognition).

```
grammar Fetal;
transaction  : begin statements end;

begin       : 'begin' ;

end         : 'end' ;   


statements  : (statement)+
            ;


statement 
            : declaration ';'
            | command ';'
            | assignment ';'
            | evaluation
            | ';'
            ;

declaration : type var;

var returns : identifier;


type returns 
            : DecimalType
            | NumberType
            | StringType 
            | BooleanType
            | DateType
            | ObjectType
            | DaoType
            ;

assignment  
            : lharg Equals rharg
            | lharg unaryOP rharg
            ;


assignmentOp    : Equals
                ;

unaryOP         : PlusEquals
                | MinusEquals
                | MultiplyEquals
                | DivideEquals
                | ModuloEquals
                | ExponentEquals
                ;

expressionOp    : arithExpressOp
                | bitwiseExpressOp
                ;

arithExpressOp  : Multiply
                | Divide
                | Plus
                | Minus
                | Modulo
                | Exponent
                ;

bitwiseExpressOp  
                : And
                | Or
                | Not
                ;

comparisonOp    : IsEqualTo
                | IsLessThan
                | IsLessThanOrEqualTo
                | IsGreaterThan
                | IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo
                | IsNotEqualTo
                ;

logicExpressOp  : AndExpression
                | OrExpression
                | ExclusiveOrExpression
                ;

rharg returns       
            : rharg expressionOp rharg
            | '(' rharg expressionOp rharg ')'
            | var
            | literal
            | assignmentCommands
            ;

lharg returns : var;

identifier  : Identifier;

evaluation : IfStatement '(' evalExpression ')'  block (Else block)?;


block : OpenBracket statements CloseBracket;


evalExpression 
                : evalExpression logicExpressOp evalExpression
                | '(' evalExpression logicExpressOp evalExpression ')'
                | eval
                | '(' eval ')'
                ;


eval : rharg comparisonOp rharg ;


assignmentCommands 
            : GetBalance '(' stringArg ')'
            | GetVariableType '(' var ')'
            | GetDescription
            | Today
            | GetDays '(' startPeriod=dateArg ',' endPeriod=dateArg ')'
            | DayOfTheWeek '(' dateArg ')'
            | GetCalendarDay '(' dateArg ')'
            | GetMonth '(' dateArg ')'
            | GetYear '(' dateArg ')'
            | Import '(' stringArg ')' /* Import( path ) */
            | Lookup '(' sql=stringArg ',' argumentList ')' /* Lookup( table, SQL) */
            | List '(' sql=stringArg ',' argumentList ')' /* List( table, SQL) */
            | invocation 
            ;



command     : Print '(' rharg ')' 
            | Credit '(' amtArg ',' stringArg ')'
            | Debit '(' amtArg ',' stringArg ')'
            | Ledger '(' debitOrCredit ',' amtArg ',' acc=stringArg ',' desc=stringArg ')'
            | Alias '(' account=stringArg ',' name=stringArg ')'
            | MapFile ':' stringArg
            | invocation
            | Update '(' sql=stringArg ',' argumentList ')'
            ;

invocation 
            : o=objectLiteral '.' m=identifier '('argumentList? ')'
            | o=objectLiteral '.' m=identifier '()'
            ;

argumentList 
            : rharg   (',' rharg )*
            ;

amtArg  : rharg ;

stringArg : rharg ;

numberArg : rharg ;

dateArg : rharg ;

debitOrCredit : charLiteral ;

literal 
            : numericLiteral
            | doubleLiteral
            | booleanLiteral
            | percentLiteral
            | stringLiteral
            | dateLiteral
            ;


fileName : '<' fn=Identifier ('.' ft=Identifier)? '>' ;

charLiteral     : ('D' | 'C');

numericLiteral  : Number ;

doubleLiteral   : Decimal ;

percentLiteral  : Percentage ;

booleanLiteral  : Boolean ;

stringLiteral   : String ;

dateLiteral     : Date ;

objectLiteral   : Identifier ;

daoLiteral      : Identifier ;

//Below are Token definitions

// Data Types
DecimalType     : 'decimal' ;
NumberType      : 'number' ;
StringType      : 'string' ;
BooleanType     : 'boolean' ;
DateType        : 'date' ;
ObjectType      : 'object' ;
DaoType         : 'dao' ;
/******************************************************************
 * Assignmnt operator
 ******************************************************************/
 Equals         : '=' ;

 /*****************************************************************
  * Unary operators
  *****************************************************************/
PlusEquals      : '+=' ;
MinusEquals     : '-=' ;
MultiplyEquals  : '*=' ;
DivideEquals    : '/=' ;
ModuloEquals    : '%=' ;
ExponentEquals  : '^=' ;

/*****************************************************************
 * Binary operators
 *****************************************************************/
 Plus           : '+' ;
 Minus          : '-' ;
 Multiply       : '*' ;
 Divide         : '/' ;
 Modulo         : '%' ;
 Exponent       : '^' ;

 /*************************************************************** 
  * Bitwise operators
  ***************************************************************/
  And           : '&' ;
  Or            : '|' ;
  Not           : '!' ;

 /*************************************************************
  * Compariso operators
  *************************************************************/
  IsEqualTo                 : '==' ;
  IsLessThan                : '<'  ;
  IsLessThanOrEqualTo       : '<=' ;
  IsGreaterThan             : '>'  ;
  IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo    : '>=' ;
  IsNotEqualTo              : '!=' ;

 /*************************************************************
  * Expression operators
  *************************************************************/
  AndExpression         : '&&' ;
  OrExpression          : '||' ;
  ExclusiveOrExpression : '^^' ;

// Reserve words (Assignment Commands)
GetBalance      : 'getBalance';
GetVariableType : 'getVariableType' ;
GetDescription  : 'getDescription' ;
Today           : 'today';
GetDays         : 'getDays' ;
DayOfTheWeek    : 'dayOfTheWeek' ;
GetCalendarDay  : 'getCalendarDay' ;
GetMonth        : 'getMonth' ;
GetYear         : 'getYear' ;
Import          : 'import'  ;
Lookup          : 'lookup'  ;
List            : 'list'    ;


// Reserve words (Commands)
Credit          : 'credit';
Debit           : 'debit';
Ledger          : 'ledger';
Alias           : 'alias' ;
MapFile         : 'mapFile' ;
Update          : 'update'  ;
Print           : 'print';

IfStatement : 'if';
Else        : 'else';
OpenBracket : '{';
CloseBracket : '}';

Percentage  : (Sign)? Digit+ (Dot Digit+)? '%' ;

Boolean     : 'true' | 'false';

Number      : Sign? Digit+;


Decimal     : Sign? Digit+ Dot Digit*;

Date        : Year '-' Month '-' Day;

Identifier
    :   IdentifierNondigit
        (   IdentifierNondigit
        |   Digit
        )*
    ;
String: '"' ( ESC | ~[\\"] )* '"';

/************************************************************
 * Fragment Definitions 
 ************************************************************/

fragment
ESC :   '\\' [abtnfrv"'\\]
    ;

fragment
IdentifierNondigit
    :   Nondigit
    //|   // other implementation-defined characters...
    ;
fragment
Nondigit
    :   [a-zA-Z_]
    ;

fragment
Digit
    :  [0-9]
    ;
fragment
Sign :   Plus | Minus;

fragment
Digits
    : [-+]?[0-9]+
    ;

fragment
Year
    : Digit Digit Digit Digit;

fragment
Month
    : Digit Digit;

fragment
Day
    : Digit Digit;


fragment Dot : '.';


fragment
SCharSequence
    :   SChar+
    ;

fragment
SChar
    :   ~["\\\r\n]
    |   SimpleEscapeSequence
    |   '\\\n'   // Added line
    |   '\\\r\n' // Added line
    ;


fragment    
CChar
    :   ~['\\\r\n]
    |   SimpleEscapeSequence
    ;

fragment
SimpleEscapeSequence
    :   '\\' ['"?abfnrtv\\]
    ;

ExtendedAscii
    : [\x80-\xfe]+
    -> skip
    ;
Whitespace
    :   [ \t]+
        -> skip
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
        -> skip
    ;

BlockComment
    :   '/*' .*? '*/'
        -> skip
    ;



LineComment
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]*
        -> skip
    ;
```

Comment: When I compile your grammar with 4.6, I have 5 errors. The first one is the  `end` rule without semicolon. It is much too long (400 lines) to ask a question on the specific point of sign recognition. For example, the `command` rule has nothing to do with the problem and I'm not going to try to understand the whole grammar. You should reduce it to the strict minimum of rules necessary to parse `number foo = [+]5` and `if (foo == 5 )`, or else nobody will take the time to answer your question.

Comment: I can cut it down.

Comment: By the way, 'begin' and 'end' are not supposed to have semicolons. They're not statements, they simply define the beginning and ending of a transaction.

Comment: Like begin, end is a subrule and must be written as `end : 'end' ;`. You can also simplify the transaction rule as : `transaction  : 'begin' statements 'end' ;` and delete the two begin/end subrules.

Comment: I agree, except that I have code behind begin and end. Although I could put the code in the transaction rule, it's enough code that it would make it ugly. I took all the code out for brevity's sake. I chose to use inline code (and not a listener) because I wanted more efficiency. Also, I wanted to put begin and end on a separate line because I developed an IDE for this and I wanted to be able to single step through each node.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that this use of a fragment is incorrect:

```
fragment Sign :   Plus | Minus;
```

I couldn't find anything in the reference book, but I think it needs to be changed to something like this:

```
fragment Sign :   [+-];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was using version 4.5.2-1 because every attempt to upgrade to 4.7 caused more errors and I didn't want to cause more errors while trying to solve another. I finally broke down and upgraded the libraries to 4.7, fixed the errors and the number recognition issue disappeared. It was a bug in the library, all this time.